# How to modify existing Excel file in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, excel, excel-interop

I want to modify an existing Excel file.

The following piece of code generates a duplicate modified excel file in documents folder instead of modifying the original file.

Note: the file which I want to modify is not in the `Documents` folder

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Public Class Form1

Public ExcelFolder As String
Public selectedfile As String
Public excel As Application
Public workbook As Workbook
Public sheet As Worksheet
Public r As Range
Public array(,) As Object

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ExcelFolder = "D:\monica\YUKEN\MARK\Excel"

    Dim dir As New IO.DirectoryInfo(ExcelFolder)
    Dim dir1 As IO.FileInfo() = dir.GetFiles
    Dim file As IO.FileInfo

    For Each file In dir1

        ComboBox1.Items.Add(file)

    Next

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    selectedfile = ComboBox1.GetItemText(ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
    TextBox1.Text = selectedfile

    Dim path As String
    path = ExcelFolder & "\" & selectedfile

    excel = New Application

    excel.Workbooks.Open(path)
    workbook = excel.ActiveWorkbook
    sheet = workbook.Worksheets(1)
    r = sheet.UsedRange

    ' Load all cells into 2d array.
    Array = r.Value(XlRangeValueDataType.xlRangeValueDefault)

    ' Get bounds of the array.
    Dim bound0 As Integer = array.GetUpperBound(0) 'last row number
    Dim bound1 As Integer = array.GetUpperBound(1) 'last column number

    'get total number of rows
    Dim totalrows As Integer = bound0 - 1 'since 1st row is header
    TextBox2.Text = CStr(totalrows)

    sheet.Cells(2, 12) = "YES"
    workbook.Save()
    workbook.Close()
    excel.Quit()
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel) : excel = Nothing
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook) : workbook = Nothing
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet) : sheet = Nothing

End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Do you have enough privileges to write the file? Try to open it in Excel, change, and save - can you do it?

Comment: yes i can modify it in Excel

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim cn As New OleDbConnection
 Dim cm As New OleDbCommand
cn = New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;

Data Source=C:\Documents and Settings\crysol\Desktop\TEST\Book1.xls;Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES""")
cn.Open()
With cm
    .Connection = cn
    .CommandText = "update [up$] set [name]=?, [QC_status]=?, [reason]=?, [date]=? WHERE [article_no]=?"
    cm = New OleDbCommand(.CommandText, cn)
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox2.Text)
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ComboBox1.SelectedItem)
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox3.Text)
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", DateTimePicker1.Text)
    cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", TextBox1.Text)
    cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("UPDATE SUCCESSFUL")
    con.Close()
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I have shown to add a sheet to an existing excel file and write data into the newly created sheet.

```
    Try
        Dim oXL As Excel.Application
        Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
        Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
        Dim oRng As Excel.Range
        'On Error GoTo Err_Handler
        ' Start Excel and get Application object.
        oXL = New Excel.Application

        ' Get a new workbook.
        Dim path As String = ViewState("filepath")
        oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(path)
        oSheet = CType(oXL.Worksheets.Add(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value), Excel.Worksheet)
        'oSheet.Name = "Reject_History"
        Dim totalSheets As Integer = oXL.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count
        CType(oXL.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet).Move(After:=oXL.Worksheets(totalSheets))
        CType(oXL.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(totalSheets), Excel.Worksheet).Activate()


        'Write Dataset to Excel Sheet
        Dim col As Integer = 0

        For Each dr As DataColumn In DirectCast(ViewState("DisplayNonExisting"), DataTable).Columns

            col += 1
            'Determine cell to write
            oSheet.Cells(10, col).Value = dr.ColumnName

        Next

        Dim irow As Integer = 10
        For Each dr As DataRow In DirectCast(ViewState("DisplayNonExisting"), DataTable).Rows
            irow += 1
            Dim icol As Integer = 0
            For Each c As String In dr.ItemArray
                icol += 1
                'Determine cell to write
                oSheet.Cells(irow, icol).Value = c
            Next
        Next

        ' Make sure Excel is visible and give the user control
        ' of Microsoft Excel's lifetime.
        ' oXL.Visible = True
        ' oXL.UserControl = True

        'oWB.SaveAs(path, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookDefault, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, False, False, Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
        'oWB.Close()
        oWB.Save()
        oWB.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing)
        ' Make sure you release object references.

        oRng = Nothing
        oSheet = Nothing
        oWB = Nothing
        oXL = Nothing

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try
```